# How to send email from Google Spreadsheet based on change within a specific sheet and column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automate sending an email from a spreadsheet when a user form is submitted. The form covers a number of processes (ordering fuel, receiving fuel etc) and I only want the email sent out on fuel orders - so need to restrict the alert to a specific column.

I have the pulled the below together from other examples, pretty sure I'm close but am probably missing something obvious out...

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    if(sheet.getName()=='Form Responses 1'){
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var cellcol = cell.getColumn();
    if(cellcol == 4){
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "email@email.com";
  var subject = 'New fuel order for '+cellvalue;
  var body = 'A new fuel order has been placed for ' + cellvalue + '. Please action asap: «' + ss.getUrl() + '»';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);}
    }
}
```

I had it working until I added the lines to find the cell column and the if function to continue only if the edit was in column D - previously any edit to the form responses sheet triggered a notification.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();` makes cell a `String` from google apps script perspective, not a cell, so `.getColumn()` does nothing.

Instead, I suggest having simply

```
var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
var cellcol = cell.getColumn();
  if(cellcol == 4){
  ...
```